# How to show that $\frac{X_n-a}{\sqrt n}$ approaches a Gaussian (if $X_n \sim\ \chi_{n-p}^2$)

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, chi-squared-distribution, moment-generating-function

Given that $X_n \sim\ \chi_{n-p}^2$, I think the moment generating function of $\frac{X_n-a}{\sqrt n}$ is $e^{\frac{-at}{\sqrt n}}(1-\frac{2t}{\sqrt n})^{-\frac{n-p}{2}}$. As specified in problem 4 on page 18 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/18/lecture-18.pdf), this MGF should converge to a Gaussian MGF as $n \to \infty$. What is the final form of the MGF as $n\to\infty$? I believe that the $(1-\frac{2t}{\sqrt n})^{-\frac{n-p}{2}}$ portion approaches zero, leaving $e^{\frac{-at}{\sqrt n}}$, which implies a Gaussian distribution with mean $a/\sqrt n$ and $\sigma^2 = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n\to\infty$, $a/\sqrt{n}$ becomes irrelevant if $a$ is constant and $X_n/\sqrt{n}$ would have mean
$(n-p)/\sqrt{n}$ which is of order $O(\sqrt{n})$. Could it be that there is a typo in the problem you mention and $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator is meant to be $n$?

**EDIT:**  I clearly misunderstood the question. In (a) convergence in probability is meant, but in (b) and (c) it is convergence in law. Comments below.

Comment: In the context (first "Show that $X_n/n$ approaches a constant $a,$ and find $a$"), we ought to suppose the intended expression is $(X_n-an)/\sqrt{n}.$ That will provide the needed information for a detailed analysis of the asymptotics of $X_n/n$ (which is the sequel to the exercise).

Comment: If the expression is $(X_n-an)/\sqrt{n}$ as you suspect,  I still do not see that this might converge to a Gaussian. The numerator is a "centered"  $\chi^2_{n-p}$ but the ratio is still $O(\sqrt{n})$. On the other hand it is clear that $X_n/n$ converges to a Gaussian.

Comment: @F.Tusell The point of the exercise was to show that $X_n/n$ converges to a Gaussian, which wasn't obvious to me. I believe $\frac{X_n}{n} \to E(\frac{X_n}{n})=1$ since $Var(\frac{X_n}{n}) \to 0$ as $n \to\infty$, so are we looking at a Gaussian with mean 1 and zero variance?

Comment: @Yandie, OK, I was obsessed with convergence in probability, as in (a). For (b), you have a "centered" $\chi^2$ wich will approach a normal as $n\to\infty$ (CLT); the $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator prevents the variance from growing to infinity, the variance will be 2 I believe.  For (c) the limiting distribution would be I think a causal at point 1, the limit of Gaussians whose variance goes to zero, as you say. Sorry if I confused you in my first answer.

Comment: I think you might be confused between the standard deviation and variance.  Here, the SD is $\sqrt{n}$ so indeed $(X_n-an)/\sqrt{n}$ converges to a nontrivial (Normal) distribution.

Comment: $(X_n-an)/\sqrt{n}$ yes,  I was referring in the last sentence to $X_n/n$.  This it seems to me that converges to a degenerate, causal distribution. Please correct if I am still misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: $(X_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ converges to a Normal$(0,\sqrt{2})$ distribution, which is not degenerate.  I don't know what you mean by a "causal" distribution.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the variance 2 as well. I was referring to (c) in the original problem, which is about  $X_n/n$. I have seen the name  "causal" used for distributions giving mass 1 to a single point, but that may be non-standard  in English.